# Missing right parenthesis ORA-00907

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am getting an `ORA-00907` error when I try to parse this statement. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
DELETE 
FROM teams 
WHERE is_old=0 
  AND tm_counter NOT IN (SELECT MIN(dup.tm_counter) 
                         FROM teams AS dup  
                         GROUP BY dup.name, dup.squad, dup.region);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, you can't use `AS` before a table alias, only before a column alias. So, change this part:

```
FROM teams AS dup
```

to this:

```
FROM teams dup
```